# SqlShardingDeploymentTool causes Sitecore 9.0 update 1 installation to fail during SIF installation

Tags: solr, sql-database, installation, sitecore-install-framework

I'm trying to setup a Sitecore 9.0 update 1 installation on my local machine using

- windows 10
- Solr 6.6.2
- SQL Server 2016 SP1 <del>Sql Express 2017</del>
- SIF-less 0.6.0.0

Despite a couple of annoying hickups I managed to get as far as past Solr installation, service restart, certificates setup.

The installation fails with the following output:

```
    PS>TerminatingError(Invoke-CommandTask): "The running command stopped because the preference variable 
    "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Command 
    C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xxxx.xconnect\App_Data\collectiondeployment\Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.SqlShardingDeploymentTool.exe 
    returned a non-zero exit code - (-1073741811)"
```

Its obviously the "SqlShardingDeploymentTool" that complains during installation, but I'm having a hard time finding out why.

The SIF-less test execution returns all green.

[image: Output from SIF-less test execution]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of - **I didn't fix the error, I simply avoided it** by not utilizing xconnect.

This was done by not filling out the two following fields in the SIF-less application:

- XConnect Package
- xConnect Name

Removing these fields allows the install script to complete successfully (leaving you with the Sitecore default site, which was my actual goal).

Answer (score 1):

Sql Server 2017 is not supported, you need to have Sql Server 2016 Update 1.

Please have a look on Prerequisites and Requirements at https://dev.sitecore.net/~/media/1E934A0DB5534F2CB1D98A0F4000B25C.ashx

[image]

Comment: Tried with Sql server 2016 SP1 after your message (the company has such an instance already, so I just changed connection settings in SIF-less), but to no avail. The **same** error occurred.

Comment: I updated the question to be specific to the supported database server.

Comment: Are you sure Sifless is working with Sitecore 9.0.1 ?

Comment: http://www.flux-digital.com/blog/install-sitecore-9-update-1-4-simple-steps/ claims that it works.

Comment: Is it using Sif not Sifless on your link

Comment: The blog-post uses SIF but claims that it is possible with SIF-less. SIF-less uses SIF to do the install, its simply a GUI tool that utilizes SIF. Also notable that I did manage to get the website up and running using SIF-less. Thank you for your hint on the database requirements